# Spring Data JPA: Having trouble combining native query with parameter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-8, spring-data

My repository is defined like this:

```
@Repository
public interface RefreshJobDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<RefreshJobDetailEntity, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = NATIVE_SUMMARY_QUERY_PARTIAL + " WHERE rjd.refresh_job_identifier = ?1" +
            " group by (rjd.refresh_job_identifier)) as rc")
    RefreshSummary getRefreshJobDetailSummaryById(String refreshJobId);

    interface RefreshSummary {
        // getters
    }

    String NATIVE_SUMMARY_QUERY_PARTIAL = "select ...";
}
```

When I run this, I get the following exception:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! On JDKs < 8, you need to use @Param for named parameters, on JDK 8 or better, be sure to compile with -parameters.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! On JDKs < 8, you need to use @Param for named parameters, on JDK 8 or better, be sure to compile with -parameters.

What confuses me is that I'm not using a "named parameter". It's a positional parameter. So what is this error telling me? We use position parameters elsewhere in our code and don't have the `-parameters` flag set, but this is the only native query. Don't know if that makes a difference or not? BTW, the database is Postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply refactor the code to use named parameters. It doesn't matter if it's a native query or jpql:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = NATIVE_SUMMARY_QUERY_PARTIAL + " WHERE rjd.refresh_job_identifier = :refreshJobId" +
        " group by (rjd.refresh_job_identifier)) as rc")
RefreshSummary getRefreshJobDetailSummaryById(@Param("refreshJobId") String refreshJobId);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: @user1660256 no problem, consider upvoting / marking as correct;>

Comment: I tried, but SO is making me wait 3 more minutes. LOL. And be on the lookout for a follow-up question I have!

Comment: @user1660256 there is no time limit for upvoting ;)